# Install Python in Wine on Linux: Setup-Program aborts with "access denied" error

Tags: python, installation, wine

I try to install Python 3.8 in Wine (on Linux Mint). The setup-program starts, but the installation aborts with an "access denied" error. I already tried to give the setup.exe sudo right, but that does not help.

Who knows how to install Python in Wine?

Cheers,

Ulrich

Comment: https://askubuntu.com/questions/330141/install-python-in-wine

Comment: I wonder what could be the use case of that?
Maybe you could try  `winetricks`.

Comment: I need to compile a python script into a windows exe... but I do not have Windows anywhere...

Comment: not an ideal workaround, but you could get a free  evaulation dev VM from MS to build your exe. https://developer.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/downloads/virtual-machines/